# Take all lines from one txt file and copy them to a new text file with some extras

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to take all of the lines from one text file and copy them to a new text file with some extra words and lines added

e.g.

i need to get this in the file "textA"

```
John
16
London
Boris
25
Cardiff
```

to say in the file "textB"

```
Person 1
Name is John
Age is 16
Lives in London

Person 2
Name is Boris
Age is 25
Lives in Cardiff
```

NB - this is an example and not actually the data, titles, filenames or prefaces to the text i want to use

Comment: What have you written, and what part are you stuck on? Do you not know how to open files? How to write a `for` loop? How to write to a file? How to format or concatenate strings?

Comment: @abarnert its the mixing of them all together

Comment: Show me teh codez...

Comment: i dont have any code as i am trying to create some and each time i fail

Comment: We can't help you unless we see code that you have tried.

Comment: Well, if you were following a tutorial, point us in the right direction and show us that you have attempted something.

Comment: This is basically "How do I write a computer program."  I am sure you can understand that a question that vague is impossible to answer in this format without actually writing the program for you.  Even if someone was willing to do that, you likely wouldn't be able to make the necessary modifications to it to match your real data since you didn't provide that.

Comment: I am sorry @PaulBecotte and i will learn from your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input data has a strict format, then it's as simple as reading and writing lines in a certain order.

Something like:

```
f = open('file1', 'r')
name = f.readline()
```

and then writing to a file

```
f = open('file2', 'w')
f.write('Name: ' + name + '\n')
```

or something. And then roll those two operations in a loop that contains as many operations as needed (in your case three, one for each name, age, and location). Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Since there's no attempt at a solution, I'm guessing you're stuck on the basics.